# Reinstalled windows on same drive, windows.old folder is broken

Tags: windows-7, windows, ntfs

I reinstalled windows, from within windows, on the same drive (inserted the disk while windows was running, and ran the installer). When the installation completed I had a `C:\windows.old` folder that I cannot move or traverse. It makes my backup program crash while traversing it.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a permissions error

Right click on the folder in explorer, click properties, then click on the security tab. From there, try to add "full control" permissions to your user. If that fails, you will need to take ownership of the folder from the advanced properties of the security tab.

Taking ownership and resetting permissions may break loading your old install, but it sounds like you don't care to use it.

Comment: Added permissions and did a reinstall of my backup program, and now it works. I chose this answer because I still want to backup the files in my old home folder, i.e. not remove the windows.old folder.

Comment: I still cannot copy the folder. The windows copy (ctrl+c/ctrl+v in explorer) stops `Calculating` at 316 101 files forever (but the window does not freeze) and canceling it requires a restart of explorer.exe. Teracopy crashes 21% in, while reading old files from quake. CHKDSK finds no error on the disk.

Comment: That's quite strange. Is there anything in the event log to indicate what is causing the crash or hang?

Answer (score 0):

You can use disk clean up to remove it. Below is from [Microsoft support.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/how-do-i-remove-the-windows-old-folder)

[image]

Comment: He wants to restore it, not delete it.